# on win7 capture list of recursive wildcard search matches including filenames and path

Tags: command-line

I think I said it all in title.

On Win7 system, I would like to generate a text file that lists, for example, all and only the executable files in the program files directory and all sub directories therof. I would prefer not to repeat path when multiple executables exist in one directory. Just being able to limit output to .exe files would be sooo helpful though!

QS

Comment: Much appreciated! My motivation was to have a printable list to which I can refer  that includes most of the applications installed on my 32 bit dinosaur. This will facilitate rebuilding a 64bit installation on a newer platform. So only the 'Program Files' will provide results. Referencing a nonexistent path causes incomplete script execution. Having said that. It is helpful to have an example that shows how to include more than one path. There seems to be an inconsistency in how this is working. I changed 64 bit path to adb with 1 exe and the exe there is not present in the list but dir is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following command from `powershell` console to get exactly these unique directories recursively under the the two Program files dirs which have executables

```
@('C:\Program Files', 'C:\Program Files (x86)') |
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.exe' |
Select Directory -Unique > "executable-folders.txt"
```

It will take a while to pick up all the folders, but once it finished you can open up the output `executable-folders.txt` file and you'll see something like this:

```
Directory                                  
---------                                  
C:\Program Files\7-Zip                     
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI             
C:\Program Files\AMD\amdkmpfd_un           
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio    
...
```

Comment: I should have indicatedmentioned that my motivation was to have a printable list to which I can refer of most of the applications installed in my 32 bit dinosaur. This will facilitate rebuilding a 64bit installation on a newer platform. So only the 'Program Files' will provide results. Referencing a nonexistent path causes incomplete script execution.

Comment: Some of my remarks (like thank you!) seem to be missing from above. More importantly. It seems that something isn't behaving as I assume it should. Script is complete when I have command prompt back right? Asking because I changed 'C:\Program Files (x86)' to  'C:\somename' where there was a single executable file and that filename was not in the .txt file though the path to it was. Again thanks for the quick response!